# Unable to run debug on rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, ruby-debug, rubymine-7

RubyMine is not running server in debug mode it shows the following error

```
Uncaught exception: Could not find yaml_db-0.3.0 in any of the sources
```

I tried to change yam_db to 0.3.5 in gem file but that throws another error. Why is it still showing this error?

Complete Error

```
ast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.32, debase 0.1.4) listens on 127.0.0.1:58007
Uncaught exception: Could not find yaml_db-0.3.0 in any of the sources
    /home/aitizazk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
    /home/aitizazk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    /home/aitizazk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    /home/aitizazk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
    /home/aitizazk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
    /home/aitizazk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
    /home/aitizazk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    /home/aitizazk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    /home/aitizazk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `setup'
    /home/aitizazk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/aitizazk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    /home/aitizazk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    /home/aitizazk/Rails/MyApp/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/aitizazk/Rails/MyApp/bin/rails:7:in `require_relative'
    /home/aitizazk/Rails/MyApp/bin/rails:7:in `<top (required)>'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: have you tried `gem install yaml_db`?

Comment: yes i installed yaml_db but still i am getting the same error in ruby mine